# IntelliJ gives error about reference in Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying to go though the Kotlin tutorial from [Freecode camp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9UC9DY-vIU), but have this issue with references.

IntelliJ complained that

1. Unresolved reference: greeting in sayHello() in main()
2. Unexpected
   tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line), after
   "Hi"

```
fun sayHello(greeting:String, vararg itemsToGreet: String) {
    itemsToGreet.forEach { itemToGreet ->
        println("$greeting $itemToGreet")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val interestingThings = listOf("Kotlin", "Programming", "Comic Books")
    sayHello(greeting:"Hi", itemsToGreet:"Kotlin", "Programming", "Comic Books")
}
```

It seems that assigning values to params can be done only by "=", not ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"greeting:" is a parameter name hint. Code should look like this:

```
sayHello("Hi", "Kotlin", "Programming", "Comic Books")
```

See how hints will be shown automatically.